# Arraylist dentro de Arralist, como escaneo posicion por posicion?

Tags: java, arraylist

Tengo una clase Banco con un arraylist de objetos Sucursales

```
public class Bank {

private String name;
private ArrayList<Branch> branches;

//CONSTRUCTOR
public Bank(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.branches = new ArrayList<Branch>();
}

public void addBranch(String branchName) {
    Branch newBranch = new Branch(branchName);
    branches.add(newBranch);

}
```

A su vez cada objeto Sucursal tiene un nombre y un arraylist de Clientes

```
public class Branch {

private String branchName;
private static ArrayList<Client> clients;

public Branch(String name) {
    this.branchName = name;
    this.clients = new ArrayList<Client>();
    System.out.println("Sucursal " + name + " creada.");
}
```

Y por último cada Cliente tiene un nombre y arraylist de transacciones

```
public class Client {

private String clientName;
private ArrayList<Double> transactions; // = new ArrayList<Double>()

//CONSTRUCTOR
public Client(String clientName, double initialTransactions) {
    this.clientName = clientName;
    this.transactions.add(initialTransactions);
}
```

**Necesito buscar si un cliente existe en el banco, por ende debo ir posicion por posicion dentro del arraylist de sucursales de Banco y ver si en su respectivo arraylist de clientes existe un cliente con ese nombre.**

Cual sería la manera más conveniente de hacerlo?

Porque para encontrar si existe una sucursal con *X* nombre dentro del arraylist de sucursales de Banco uso algo así:

```
//escanea nombre por nombre dentro de arraylist 
//y devuelve posicion si encuentra coincidencia

    public int findBranch(String branchName) {
            int numOfBranches = this.branches.size();
            String queryToLowerCase = branchName.toLowerCase(); 

            for (int i = 0; i < numOfBranches; i++) {
                String branchNameToLower = branches.get(i).getName().toLowerCase();
                boolean exists = queryToLowerCase.equals(branchNameToLower);
                if (exists) {
                    return i;
                }

            }
            return -1;

        }

        //devuelve el OBJETO Branch en la posicion int
        public Branch queryBranch(String name) {
            int position = findBranch(name);
            if (position >= 0) {
                return this.branches.get(position);
            }
            return null;


        }
```

Pero el mismo funcionamiento/razonamiento no me sirve para lo que necesito porque en ese caso sólo hay 1 objeto Banco con arraylist de Sucursales, mientras que ahora tengo varios objetos Sucursales que a su vez tienen arraylists de Clientes y no se como ir posición por posición en el arraylist de Sucursales escaneando su respectivo arraylist de Clientes hasta que encuentre o no el nombre de cliente pasado.

Comment: Lo que pudiste hacer, es crear un algoritmo que busque el nombre de X sucursal, ahora lo que quieres es un algoritmo que encuentre el nombre de X cliente de X sucursal? También hay que recalcar que en cada sucursal puede repetirse el nombre. ¿Que harás al respecto si el nombre se llegara a repetir en varias sucursales?

Answer (score 0):

Primero que nada si tu desarrollaste la lógica de negocios esta mal desarrollada, en la vida real un clientes tiene una cuenta en un banco y el cliente puede hacer transacciones en cualquier sucursal por lo que un cliente no tiene una relación 1 a 1 cliente-sucursal no sin haber un objeto transacción de por medio es decir cliente-transacción-sucursal, si solo es para un ejercicio donde no importa la logica de negocios solo itera 2 veces el objeto pero ten en cuenta que como la logica del negocio esta mal ese cliente se puede encontrar en 2 sucursales como tu pregunta es solo saber si el cliente existe basta con que lo encuentres la primera vez para retornar un valor de existencia(true) caso contrario (false).

Entonces tendrías algo así como;

```
public boolean containsClient(Bank bank, String clientName){
  for(Branch branch : bank.getBranches){
    for(Client client : branch.getClients){
      if(client.getClientName.compareTo(clientName) == 0){
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Acá va un ejemplo para que veas como acceder a cada lista, la lógica del programa no es muy real, pero es con fines didácticos

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Banco3 {

    public static Bank banco;

    public static Scanner scannerInt;
    public static Scanner scannerDouble;
    public static Scanner scannerString;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        scannerInt =new Scanner(System.in);
        scannerDouble =new Scanner(System.in);
        scannerString =new Scanner(System.in);

        banco =new Bank("Banco Nación");    

        //agregamos 3 Branch, método propio de Bank
        getBanco().addBranch("Capital Federal");
        getBanco().addBranch("Santa Fe");
        getBanco().addBranch("Córdoba");        

        //hacemos que se repita mientras respuesta sea ="s"
        String rta =null;
        do{
            mostrarMenuSucursales();
            agregarClienteASucursal();
            System.out.println("Desea agregar otro? Presione tecla s en caso afirmativo");
            rta =scannerString.nextLine();

        }while(rta.equalsIgnoreCase("s"));

        System.out.println("Lista de todos los clientes del banco:");
        mostrarTodosLosClientesDelBanco();

        String entradaString =null;
        System.out.println("Desea comprobar si existe un cliente en el banco? "
                    + "Presione tecla s en caso afirmativo");
        rta =scannerString.nextLine();
        while(rta.equalsIgnoreCase("s")){
            System.out.println("Ingrese nombre del Cliente:");
            entradaString =scannerString.nextLine();
            if(existeCliente(entradaString)) System.out.println("Existe");
            else System.out.println("No existe");
            System.out.println("Desea comprobar otro? "+"Presione tecla s en caso afirmativo");
            rta =scannerString.nextLine();            
        }

    }
    //geter
    public static Bank getBanco() {
        return banco;
    }
    public static void mostrarMenuSucursales(){
        //por ej. para agregar un Client a Capital Federal, sabemos que está en posición 0, o sea
        //que haciendo getBanco().getBranches().get(0) podes acceder a esa Branch pero
        //mejor mostramos una lista de Branch y le asignamos un número a cada una para
        //luego escoger con el scanner
        List<Branch> branches =getBanco().getBranches();
        System.out.println("Elija una Sucursal:");
        int longitBranches =branches.size();
        //recorremos lista para mostrar
        for (int i = 0; i < longitBranches; i++) {
            System.out.println("Nº "+(i+1)+":  "+branches.get(i).getBranchName());
        }
    }
    public static void agregarClienteASucursal(){
        //recogemos valor
        int entradaInt =scannerInt.nextInt();
        //ya tenemos la referencia a la sucursal escogida, ahora accedemos a esa
        //Branch y usamos el método propio de esta clase, addCliente(String name ,double initialTransaction)
        //para agregar Client

        //pedimos nombre y transaccion
        System.out.println("Ingrese nombre del cliente:");
        String entradaString =scannerString.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Ingrese transacción inicial del cliente:");
        double entradaDouble =scannerDouble.nextDouble();

        getBanco().getBranchPorNumero(entradaInt).addCliente(entradaString, entradaDouble);       
    }
    public static void mostrarTodosLosClientesDelBanco(){
        int longitBrench =getBanco().getBranches().size();
        for (int i = 0; i < longitBrench; i++) {
            int longitClient =getBanco().getBranches().get(i).getClients().size();
            for (int j = 0; j < longitClient; j++) {
                System.out.println("Cliente: "+getBanco().getBranches().get(i).getClients().get(j).getClientName()
                +",  Sucursal: "+getBanco().getBranches().get(i).getBranchName()
                +",  Transacción inicial:  "+getBanco().getBranches().get(i).getClients().get(j).getTransactions().get(0));
                //habria que hacer más métodos u otro for anidado para mostrar cada transacción de cada Client pero por
                //lo menos mostramos la inicial que sabemos qu está en posición 0
            }
        }
    }
    public static boolean existeCliente(String nombre){
        //por mayor simplicidad uso for mejorado, pero es igual al de mostrarTodosLosClientesDelBanco()
        List<Branch> branches =getBanco().getBranches();
        List<Client> clientes =null;

        for(Branch bra:branches){

            clientes =bra.getClients();
            for(Client cli:clientes){
                if(cli.getClientName().equalsIgnoreCase(nombre))
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
class Bank {

    private String name;
    private List<Branch> branches;

    public Bank(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.branches = new ArrayList<Branch>();
    }
    public void addBranch(String branchName) {
        Branch newBranch = new Branch(branchName);
        branches.add(newBranch);
    }
    //geters
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public List<Branch> getBranches() {
        return branches;
    }
    /**
     * Devuelve un Branch correspondiente al número ingresado por parámetro
     * @param num Es el número de referecia que figura en el menú, no confundir con el índice del array,
     * ya que este es una unidad menor.
     * @return Branch
     */
    public Branch getBranchPorNumero(int num){
        return branches.get(num-1);
    }
}
class Branch {

    private String branchName;
    private List<Client> clients;

    public Branch(String name) {
        branchName = name;
        clients = new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.println("Sucursal " + name + " creada.");
    }
    public void addCliente(String name ,double initialTransaction){
        Client cli =new Client(name, initialTransaction);
        clients.add(cli);
    }
    //geters
    public String getBranchName() {
        return branchName;
    }
    public List<Client> getClients() {
        return clients;
    }    

}
class Client {

    private String clientName;
    private List<Double> transactions;

    public Client(String clientName, double initialTransaction) {
        this.clientName = clientName;
        transactions =new ArrayList<>();
        transactions.add(initialTransaction);
    }
    public void addTransaction(double trans){
        transactions.add(trans);
    }
    //geters
    public String getClientName() {
        return clientName;
    }
    public List<Double> getTransactions() {
        return transactions;
    }   
}
```